# Get Next Execution Date from given date with Quartz Cron Expression

Tags: java, date, cron, quartz

I am trying to get Next Execution Date based on a Start Date and a Cron Expression using Quartz Cron Expression utility in Java. (`org.quartz.CronExpression`)

Following is my code to get **next execution date**

```
CronExpression exp = new CronExpression(cronExpression);
Date nextExecutionDate = exp.getNextValidTimeAfter(startDate);
```

Cron Expression is: `0 0 */1 ? * *` *(every 1 hour)*

Input Start Date is: `2020-06-15T16:41:00.00`

Current Output of Next Execution Date is: `2020-06-15T17:00:00.000`

However, I expect the output of Next Execution Date as `2020-06-15T17:41:00.000`

Kindly share some pointers to achieve the expected output. Do I need to alter the Cron Expression or do I need to add some time offset from start date? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should alter the cron expression like

```
0 41 */1 ? * *
```